# Expresión regular para validar que un numero tenga como símbolo decimal la coma

Tags: javascript, java, string, regex, lenguaje-agnóstico

Como creo una expresión regular que valide si un String es:

- un numero
- [opcional] coma `,` decimal
- [obligatorio si coma] otro numero

Además:

- **NO** tiene punto `.` como símbolo de miles

He intentado crearla:

```
[0-9,]+[^.]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/X43uNbM0EERtm8NF)

Pero los resultados:

```
22,33        CORRECTO
33.44        INCORRECTO
22,33...     CORRECTO // PERO DEBERIA SER INCORRECTO!!!
232.33dfdfd  CORRECTO // PERO DEBERIA SER INCORRECTO!!!
```

Resultados esperados:

```
22,33        CORRECTO
225,3432     CORRECTO
33.44        INCORRECTO
22,33...     INCORRECTO
23,          INCORRECTO
```

Comment: Yo lo dejaría en `"[\d,]+"`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza esa expresión sigue pasando los dos últimos casos que he puesto... incluso pasa `232.33`

Comment: ¿Necesitas que sea regex? ¿No puedes parsearlo con una librería de formato de números?

Comment: debe ser `regex` porque se va a usar en la validación en cliente (`javascript`) i servidor (`java`) y quiero que sea igual en ambos casos...

Comment: Pues yo veo que no acierta con toda la cadena de ejemplo, solo con parte(s) de ella (mucho cuidado al interpretar los resultados). Yo veo que al colocar `232.33dfdf` y evaluarlo contra `[\d,]+` me marca 232 y 33 por separado.

Comment: Como recomendación: **Ten cuidado con reutilizar regex en dos lenguajes distintos**: los regex de Java no tienen porque tener la misma sintaxis u opciones que JavaScript

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz una regex es igual en cualquier lenguaje, simplemente tienes que controlar los caracteres de escape y el parseador... pero no la expresión

Comment: @JordiCastilla La sintaxis básica si pero algunos tienen mas carterísticas que otros

Comment: claro @CarlosMuñoz, pero **1)** puedes hacerlo todo con sintaxis básica (aunque sea bastante más complicado) y **2)** con lo que necesito, tampoco hay una necesidad de hacer virguerías con las regex y por tanto, la solución es única para los dos casos. Soy muy del [KISS :)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_KISS) aunque a veces me obceco... xDDDD

Comment: Sí era solo una recomendación general. Por eso dice "Ten cuidado" y no dice "No lo hagas" =)

Comment: `\d+(,\d{1,2})` si quieres que solo admita 2 decimales.  Util para precios por ejemplo

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Intenta con esta expresión

```
^[0-9]+([,][0-9]+)?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ah_JuglZGAIK_gqO)

Comment: No es necesario poner la coma en una clase de caracteres (entre corchetes), ni escaparla. Las comas no tienen ningún significado especial en un regex (no son metacaracteres), por lo que se interpretan literalmente. Recomendaría editar dejando la expresión `^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?$`, que tiene el mismo significado y no da lugar a malas interpretaciones.

Answer (score 5):

esta debería ser tu expresión

```
\d+(,\d+)?
```

recuerda que si lo pasas a una función como cadena debes escapar las diagonales, así:

```
"\\d+(,\\d+)?"
```

Answer (score 4):

Esta expresión acepta negativos, usa `\d` en vez de `[0-9]`, sin crear grupos innecesarios, ni escapar caracteres que no hace falta:

```
^-?\d+(?:,\d+)?$
```

Alternativamente, si se quiere aceptar notación científica (ej: `1.2e+05`):

```
^-?\d+(?:,\d+)?(?:[Ee][-+]?\d+)?$
```

<kbd>[Demo en regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/a4xXO6/1/)</kbd>

[image: Imagen de visualización del algoritmo del regex generada en regexper.com]

---

Algunas notas sobre las diferencias:

**Negativos**. Es un error común olvidarse que un número también puede ser negativo y empezar con un `-`. Espero que sirva para evitar dolores de cabeza cuando el código ya está en producción.

**Usando `\d`**. En algunos lenguajes, `\d` coincide con [dígitos de otros alfabetos](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm). Entre los grandes: Python3, los de .Net, Perl, C/C++ (con boost), R, TCL o en Oracle. Si se quiere evitar ese detalle, ahí sí reemplazaríamos todas las `\d` por `[0-9]`. Pero para el resto, `\d` es exactamente lo mismo que `[0-9]` y visualmente queda mejor.

**Sin crear grupos innecesarios**. Cuando se usan paréntesis, no solo se está agrupando, también se está capturando el texto con el que coincide ese grupo. Pero existen [**grupos sin captura**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), cuya sintaxis es `(?:subpatrón)`, para evitar usar memoria innecesaria. Además, es más sencillo para quien esté leyendo tu regex, porque queda claro que estás agrupando pero no te interesa recuperar esa parte.
<sub>-*Ya sé, al principio cuesta leer esos `?` y `:` de más, que no es un cuantificador, pero te aseguro que en poco tiempo se lee de corrido y se comprende automáticamente*.</sub>

**Sin escapar lo que no hace falta**. La coma (`,`) no es un [metacaracter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/49215/127) en regex. Como tal, no hace falta escaparla (ni `\,`, ni `[,]`), simplemente la `,` en la expresión regular se toma como literal.

**Java** no tiene ninguna opción de literales de string ☹. Es el único lenguaje (que tengo presente) donde hay que escapar cada barra para usar este regex:

- Código:

  ```java
  Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^-?\\d+(?:,\\d+)?(?:[Ee][-+]?\\d+)?$").matcher(texto);
  if (matcher.find()) {
      //Número válido
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Con esta expresión regular validas que los números estén separados por comas para los miles sin decimales.

```
[0-9]{1,3}(\,[0-9]{3})
```

Ejemplo:

- 100,000 -> Correcto
- 100 -> Correcto
- 10,00 -> Incorrecto
- 10,000 -> Correcto

La puedes validar en http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
 var patron= /^[0-9]+([.])?([0-9]+)?$/;
```

Es mejor esta porque, te permite poner solo enteros en caso necesario,
y si pones un punto solo te lo acepta, o con decimales, te dejo unos caso de escenarios

> ```
> 123
> 123.
> 123.00
> 123.0215
> ```

Debuggex Demo
https://www.debuggex.com/r/X43uNbM0EERtm8NF

Answer (score 0):

Con esta te valida que tenga 1 o 2 caracteres después del punto decimal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no siendo obligatorio colocarle decimales.

^[0-9]+([.][0-9]{1,2})?$

https://www.debuggex.com/r/qTPyvu3WB9xuUCaj

Answer (score -1):

Si entiendo bien tu descripción la siguiente cadena sería un número válido :

```
22,
```

Para que esa cadena también fuese aceptada la expresión regular sería :

```
    ^[0-9]+([,][0-9]*)?$
```

[image: Regular expression 1 visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/b0ljGd_syV6xBWDz)

Importante incluir los anclajes (anchor) de principio de cadena `^` y de final de cadena `$`.
Sin el anclaje `$` la cadena `232.33dfdfd` como correcta cuando no lo es.

Si `22,` no es una cadena correcta entonces la expresión regular a usar es :

```
^[0-9]+([,][0-9]+)?$
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/VCmaMxf5XO97JlM_)

Comment: jose, me había expresado mal quizás, he aclarado la pregunta, la respuesta de @Kristian es la que necesito. Gracias de todas formas.

Comment: ¿Estas seguro? La respuesta de @Kristian acepta `232.33dfdfd` pese a que no debiera.

Comment: no, no lo hace, era una typo, mira el historial de ediciones y mis comentarios, pero gracias! :)

Comment: Pues sí, acaba de editarla. Le falta editar el enlace a Debuggex Demo todavía, pero ya casi lo tiene.

Comment: lo he hecho yo mismo para que no haya confusiones ;)