# ¿Cómo permitir solo dígitos y solo un punto o una coma en un input?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

Como permitir solo dígitos y solo un punto o una coma en un input con regex en javascript para formateo en angularjs.

```
link: (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) => {
        if (!modelCtrl) return;
        modelCtrl.$parsers.unshift((inputValue) => {
          if (inputValue === undefined) return '';
          const transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/(?<=^| )\d+(\.\d+)?(?=$| )|(?<=^| )\.\d+(?=$| )/g, '').replace('.', ',');
          if (transformedInput.indexOf(',') === -1 && inputValue.length >= 11) {
            transformedInput = inputValue.replace(/[^\d.,]/g, '').replace(/\d{12}/g, inputValue.substr(0, 11));
          }
          if (inputValue !== transformedInput) {
            modelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
            modelCtrl.$render();
          }
          return transformedInput;
```

Comment: duplicado de http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2831/expresi%C3%B3n-regular-para-validar-que-un-numero-tenga-como-s%C3%ADmbolo-decimal-la-coma

Comment: cierto, es esa misma respuesta pero añadiendo el punto junto a la coma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El regex que buscas es:

<strike>`^\d+([.,]{1}\d+)?$`</strike>    `^\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?$`   (gracias al comentario de Mariano)

Solo se permiten dígitos seguidos de la posibilidad de 1 punto o 1 coma y más dígitos.

```
Pruebas | Resultado
      1   true
      1.  false
      1,  false
    11.1  true  
    1,52  true
```