# Permitir solo números enteros y decimales en un input al escribir

Tags: html, jquery, regex

Busque información pero solo lo valida cuando termine de escribir, por ejemplo el siguiente código:

```js
$('.number').on('input', function () { 
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Primer Input</p>
<input type="text"  pattern="^[0-9]{0,12}([,][0-9]{2,2})?$" class="form-control" required /><br>

<p>Segundo Input</p>
<input type="text" class="form-control number" required /><br><br>
```

El primer input valida números enteros y decimales, pero no al momento de escribir. El segundo input sí valida al momento de escribir, no se mucho de expresiones regulares así que solamente copie y pegue la expresión para que pueda validar como el segundo input, pero no funciona.

```js
$('.number').on('input', function () { 
  this.value = this.value.replace(/^[0-9]{0,12}([,][0-9]{2,2})?$/g,'');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control number" required />
```

Si me podrían ayudar, **si no me entendieron:** quiero que valide como el segundo input, al escribir no me permita colocar letras, solo números enteros y decimales, gracias a todos.

Comment: la segunda expresión es una clase de bootstrap eso te sirve del lado del cliente, podrías intentar a hacer una combinación, intenta y mira si te funciona algo asi: <input type="text"  pattern="^[0-9]{0,12}([,][0-9]{2,2})?$" class="form-control number" required /><br>

Comment: Si funciona pero lo que quiero es que no pueda escribir letras, solo numeros enteros y decimales con punto

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Expresión regular para validar que un numero tenga como símbolo decimal la coma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2831/expresi%c3%b3n-regular-para-validar-que-un-numero-tenga-como-s%c3%admbolo-decimal-la-coma)

Comment: La he votado duplicada porque en [este](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/411039/permitir-solo-n%c3%bameros-enteros-y-decimales-en-un-input-al-escribir#comment735013_411044) comemtario planteas que sólo necesitas la expresión regular.

Comment: @MauricioContreras pero no esta con la funcion `on`, esto se tiene que validar cuando escribe. Probe la exprecion, lo puse en el `on` pero tampoco funciona, nose si lo estoy colocando mal, podrias dar una respuesta ponienda dicha exprecion en el `on` correctamente?

Comment: Si necesitas validar cuando escribe, debes usar el evento `keyup`, y no el evento `input`. Por otro lado, no lo tomes a mal, pero se escribe *expresión* y no *expreción*. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de si esto es lo que buscas,
Asi que no añadiré explicación aún.

```js
function limitDecimalPlaces(e, count) {
  if (e.target.value.indexOf('.') == -1) { return; }
  if ((e.target.value.length - e.target.value.indexOf('.')) > count) {
    e.target.value = parseFloat(e.target.value).toFixed(count);
  }
}

function isNumberKey(evt)
{
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;

  return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" oninput="limitDecimalPlaces(event, 2)" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"  />
```

Comment: Evita mezclar lógica con presentación. Los atributos `oninput` y `onkeypress` mezclan la lógica con la presentación. Es preferible usar `element.addEventListener()`. Por otro lado, yo usaría el evento `keyup` antes (en vez) que el evento `keypress`. Saludos

Comment: Si es lo que quiero, pero hay alguna forma de hacerlo por exprecion regular? O mas bien, porque la exprecion regular que se usa en el primer input funciona y cuando lo pongo con el `on` no funciona

Answer (score 0):

```js
function isNumberKey(evt) {
  var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 &&
    (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;

  return true;
}
```

```html
<INPUT id="txtChar" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" name="txtChar">
```

Comment: Aparte del código, deberias explicarlo para que se entienda mejor la respuesta. Mírate [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)... Aparte de eso, he probado tu código y solo permite decimales de punto (en mi localización usamos coma, por ejemplo) y ademas me permite poner tantos puntos como quiera.  Si bien se aproxima a la solución, no es una buena respuesta aun.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque ha pasado mucho tiempo aquí dejo una solución para futuros desarrolladores.

Puedes ver el orden de las teclas en este [enlace](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/codigos-ascii/punto-y-coma-codigo-ascii-59.html)

El siguiente input solo acepta números y punto (.), lo validamos con keypress:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode < 46 || event.keyCode > 57 || event.keyCode == 47) event.returnValue = false;" required />
```