# Cómo hacer una expresión regular que incluya o excluya a todos los caracteres de codigo ASCII en C#?

Tags: c#, regex, ascii

Estoy usando este código que he sacado de la web de Microsoft que supuestamente sirve para eliminar caracteres invalidos de un string.

El tema es que no funciona correctamente y creo que es debido a la exresión regular que está usando porque tambíen me elimina caracteres que sin son validos.

El código es el siguiente:

```
        ///--------------------------------------------------
        using System;
        using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
        
        public class Example
        {
            static string CleanInput(string strIn)
            {
                // Replace invalid characters with empty strings.
                try {
                   return Regex.Replace(strIn, @"[^\w\.@-]", "",
                                        RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
                }
                // If we timeout when replacing invalid characters,
                // we should return Empty.
                catch (RegexMatchTimeoutException) {
                   return String.Empty;
                }
            }
        }   
    
    ///-------------------------------------------------- 
    public class MainClass
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            ///Supòner que este string contine carecteres invalios al final de la cadena
            string str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
            string CleanInput(str)
            Console.Write(s);
        }
    }
    ///--------------------------------------------------
```

El resultado que obtengo es:
`12345678910`
Cuando supuestamente debería obtener lo siguiente
`1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`

¿Sabe alguien como hacer una expresión regular para poder eliminar cualquier caracter que no pertenezca al codigo ASCII?

[Fuente del código](https://docs.microsoft.com/ca-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-strip-invalid-characters-from-a-string)

He estado mirando la documentación pero no veo la forma de hacerlo correctamente.
[La documentación de expresiones regulares](https://docs.microsoft.com/ca-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions)

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: El enlace que compartes dice "CleanInput strips out all nonalphanumeric characters except periods (.), at symbols (@), and hyphens (-), and returns the remaining string". No sé por qué dices que supuestamente debe permitir comas. Incluye la coma en los carácteres no alfanuméricos que quieres permitir y ya está.

Comment: ¿Cómo las incluyo?... Perdona, es que no tengo nada de experiencia con expresiones regulares... es la primera vez que uso una... las veo y es como si fuera chino mandarín...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba cambiando la expresión por

```
Regex.Replace(
    strIn, 
    @"[^\w\.\,@-]", 
    "", 
    RegexOptions.None, 
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5)
);
```

Para que no reemplace la coma por *nada*. Para aprender a usar la magia oscura de las expresiones regulares, puedes jugar en sitios como [este](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_csharp_online.php) o [este otro](https://regexr.com/).

Y, ya sabes, lee la documentación del código que usas antes de decir qué debería hacer *supuestamente*.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Alfabravo!! Funciona perfectamente!! Y muchisimas gracias por los enlaces tambíen. Lo haré, tendré mas cuidado al leer y al comentar!! Saludos y Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con la siguiente expresión

```
^[0-9]+([,][0-9]+)?$
```

Fuente: [Expresión regular para validar que un numero tenga como símbolo decimal la coma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2831/expresi%C3%B3n-regular-para-validar-que-un-numero-tenga-como-s%C3%ADmbolo-decimal-la-coma)

Comment: Gracias Oscar: Asi las comas no desaparecen...  pero los caracteres no deseados tampoco... la salida que obtengo es la siguiente:  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12?????????????????????? ¿Tal vez debería combinar la expresion que tu me has dado con esta otra @"[^\w\.@-]" ?