# Permitir comas en expresión regular Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo esta variable con una expresión regular:

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-ZÑñÁ-Úá-úÀ-Ùà-ùÄ-Üä-ü]+$/;
```

Me gustaría saber si es posible añadir a esta expresión regular para que también detecte las comas entre palabras es decir si tengo por ejemplo:

Madrid,Barcelona,Valencia que me detecte esa cadena.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esta expresión:

```
\d+(,\d+)?
```

Mira este enlace, tiene varias opciones: [Expresión regular para validar que un numero tenga como símbolo decimal la coma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2831/expresi%C3%B3n-regular-para-validar-que-un-numero-tenga-como-s%C3%ADmbolo-decimal-la-coma)

Seguro encuentras aquí la solución. Un saludo